# Is there a way to save/restore applications in Windows 10 (to an init state)?

Tags: windows

For example, I boot up.

A lot of times I'll use split screens for a: code editor, web browser (or two), Photoshop, and say an instance of Windows Media Player for video. Is there anything out there that will allow me to pull these programs up in their initial positions to avoid the repetitive task of setting them up each and every single day?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Built in support for remembering and restoring window sizes and positions is at best limited (and at worst, nonfunctional) in Windows 10.

You may have success with a third-party program, such as [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/) (the free version [should be sufficient](https://www.displayfusion.com/Compare/)). Alternatives such as [AquaSnap](https://www.nurgo-software.com/pricing/aquasnap) or [Divvy](http://mizage.com/windivvy/) are also available, although these are not free.